# Exercise with flux lines of a vector field

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $V\in \mathfrak X (\mathbb R^3)$ be defined as $-y\frac \partial {\partial x} +x \frac \partial {\partial y}$. I found that the general solution of the differential equation induced by $V$ is: $$\gamma(t)= a e^{it}\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix} + b e^{-it}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i \\0  \end{pmatrix}+ c \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\1  \end{pmatrix}.$$ Trying to find the flux line passing for a fixed point $p\in \mathbb R^3$ at $t=0$ I realized that, fixed the real constants $a,b,c$, it is impossible that the flux line obtained stays always in $\mathbb R^3$. However the exercise supposes that I work with the real field, so I'm quite confused by this exercise. Does anyone have some clarify? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why require that $a,b,c$ be real? The real solutions may have complex values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: By “flux lines” you mean flow lines or integral curves? Flux has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with complex exponentials try working with trigonometric functions ($\sin t,\cos t)$ since they satisfy the same second order ODE that you had to solve to arrive here. That way your answer will contain no complex constants in the end. Although even in your answer a complex choice of constants can end up giving a real solution.